# How to sign out of Gmail on iPhone X in the iPhone mail.app

Tags: ios, mail.app

The iPhone mail app has changed. I cannot figure out how to sign out or switch email accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings app on your phone and scroll down to "Passwords & Accounts". Tap that, and find your Google account listed on this page. Tap the account and you'll see a button labeled "Delete Account."

[image]

Comment: The image doesn’t mimic the screen you’re talking about

Answer (score 0):

## Signing Out/Deleting

Go to Settings -> Passwords & Accounts.

Look for the Accounts section.

Click on the account you want to disable and press the switch to de-select mail:

[image]

If you want to delete the account scroll to the bottom and click Delete Account!

[image: delete]

## Switching Accounts

Go to mail.app and at the top you will see all your accounts under All Inboxes and you can switch accounts there. Tap on All Inboxes to see emails from all accounts.

Comment: This won't sign out from the account, just disable it

Comment: @EzekielElin was just editing my answer to add that

Comment: @Kelly no problem. If my answer helped please press the tick next to my answer. Thanks